# Can't Add new Views after declaring RootViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I recently started developing iOS apps in swift and I'm trying to make an iBeacon App using [this](http://ibeaconmodules.us/blogs/news/14702963-tutorial-swift-based-ibeacon-app-development-with-corelocation-on-apple-ios-7-8) tutorial.

I want to Embed the ViewController in a navigationController, but I don't know what should I change in this lines of code:

```
let viewController:ViewController = window!.rootViewController as ViewController
viewController.beacons = beacons as CLBeacon[]?
viewController.tableView.reloadData()
```

As the RootViewController is no longer the ViewController.

Note: The code is in the AppDelegate.

Comment: have you added navigation controller in storyboard?

Comment: Yes, Editor > Embed in > Navigation Controller.
I re-run the app and get the following error:
Could not cast value of type 'UINavigationController' (0x39962830) to 'iBeaconTemplateSwift.ViewController' (0x120638).
(lldb)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
let navController:UINavigationController = window!.rootViewController as UINavigationController
let viewController:ViewController = navController.viewControllers[0] as ViewConroller
```

Comment: Thanks this worked in fact, I tried something similar before but i was using
navController.viewControllers.first and didn't seem to work :/

Answer (score 0):

Try this similar

var window: UIWindow?
    var viewController: ViewController?
    var navigationController: UINavigationController?

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)




    viewController = ViewController()
    navigationController = UINavigationController (rootViewController: viewController!)
    self.window?.rootViewController = navigationController
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    return true
}
```